# Custom Delete Cache implementation in iOS Settings app

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking for a way to delete an iOS application cache by using the phone's Settings app.

I have found a few apps that have a switch in their's app Settings page, for example the Zara app has this "Delete cache" switch, which clears the cache the next time the app is opened.

[image]

I am looking to implement something similar, but I'm not sure how can I display these custom actions in the app's settings page.

Comment: Do you know how to setup a Settings.bundle in your app? That's all it is. Add a boolean setting. Check it when the app returns to the foreground or starts up next. Act on the value as desired.

Comment: No, I did not know about Settings.bundle. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction & for the overview of how it should be implemented!

Comment: You can also present this setting in-app using e.g. [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be archived by using a `Settings Bundle`. Just add it to you Project and follow the Guide provided by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW5).

[image]